# Appending values to a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

This code appends a new value directly to a tuple. But, tuples are supposed to be nonchangeable. Could someone explain what is happening here?

```
word_frequency = [('hello', 1), ('my', 1), ('name', 2),
('is', 1), ('what', 1), ('?', 1)]

def frequency_to_words(word_frequency):
  frequency2words = {}
  for word, frequency in word_frequency:
    if frequency in frequency2words:
      frequency2words[frequency].append(word)
    else:
      frequency2words[frequency] = [word]
  return frequency2words

print(frequency_to_words(word_frequency))
```

Result: `{1: ['hello', 'my', 'is', 'what', '?'], 2: ['name']}`

Comment: Tuples are enclosed in `()`, lists are enclosed in `[]`. Only the former is immutable

Comment: "This code appends a new value directly to a tuple." No, it doesn't do that anywhere

Comment: Yeah, I kinda can see that now. Sorry for the confusion. I know this might seem like basic stuff for you guys but its hard for me to grasp programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line makes a list []

```py
frequency2words[frequency] = [word]
```

That's what you are .append()'ing to.

But you can do `(1,2) + (3,4)` and Python will make a bigger tuple to hold four things and copy them in, to make it look like it works. What you can't do is mutate the contents of a () tuple:

```py
>>> t = (1,2)
>>> t[0] = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    t[0] = t
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.append()` operation is done on the list values in the `frequency2words` dictionary, *not* the tuples in `word_frequency`.

You can rewrite your code to be more concise using `.setdefault()`, which should also make it more clear what you're appending to.

```py
def frequency_to_words(word_frequency):
  frequency2words = {}
  for word, frequency in word_frequency:
      frequency2words.setdefault(frequency, []).append(word)
  return frequency2words
```